# QMessageBox wait for function to complete and then close PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Very new to PyQt5, but I would like to have a message box that waits for a function to complete and then closes once it has completed. This is what I have tried:

```
msg = QMessageBox()
msg.setWindowTitle("File Uploading...")
msg.setText("                Please Wait...                   ")
msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.NoButton)
msg.exec()
Ui_MainWindow.pdfImageCreator(filename) #This may take a long time 
msg.done(1) #Close message box once done
```

But the application just opens the message box and never tries to run the function after it, is there anyway to allow the message box to open and then continue to run the code until it is close?

Comment: This can be achieved with signals and slots, but I'm worried about what `pdfImageCreator` does: if you're not careful and that process is not done in a different thread, it will block the UI. Edit your question including a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and we'll try to help you. Also, be aware that it seems like you're calling a class method (which doesn't seem to be a good approach from the look of your example), and that you should *never* edit the output of pyuic to create your programs, but use it as an imported module instead.

Comment: Oh no... I am new to coding in general and especially to PyQt5, I did  all my editing in pyuic file and its over 1000 lines of code all running my application. But everything is working and the last thing I need is to fix this as the window becomes not responding when running `pdfImageCreator` due to it converting pdf pages into .pngs which can take some time depending on the length of the PDF.

Comment: Don't worry, it's a common mistake. I suggest you to rewrite your code to integrate the pyuic output by following the official docs on [using Designer with PyQt](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) (the third method, the multiple inheritance approach, is usually the best). It'll take some time, but it's worth the effort; keeping UI and programming separated is always a good thing: as soon as you need to change something in the GUI, it's just a matter of rebuilding the ui file, otherwise you'll have plenty of headaches to integrate the changes with existing code.

Comment: After you've done that, edit your question and add the pyuic output (or the ui file). Please ensure to provide a *minimal* example which could be *reproducible*. It's something that will require some time to achieve, but making it as simple as possible will seriously increase the possibility of people helping you: a lot of users are just not interested in answering questions that have examples that are unnecessary complex and require too much time to understand the code logic behind them, and you'll end up losing the opportunity to have an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, this project is due soon so I will try on making it work the way you've explained to me. But its a lot of code and it was very temperamental in the first place, I am very worried to be messing with it. For now I think I will just implement a message before the long function and then a Done message once it is complete, as a very lazy work around until I rewrite all the code. Thanks again!